# Kafka consumer is not reading message sent by producer if started after producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I found property auto.offset.reset=earliest or auto.offset.reset=latest.

Now here is my scenario with 1 Topic, 1 partition,1 consumer

For example, i have started producer. Producer send 100 records to Topic. Now i start the consumer. According to the property auto.offset.reset=earliest my consumer will start reading record from 0 index of partition. 
Now if my consumer does async commit for 1-100 record and goes down. Meanwhile producer send 100 records more. When consumer comes up, will it start reading message from 0 index of partition or will it start reading from 101 index of partition and process the record from 101 to 200.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka 0.9 onwards if your commit is successful Kafka will store the progress of the consumer in a special internal topic `__consumer_offsets`. This topic stores  the offset consumed by each consumer group on a topic and partition.

So when your consumer is started again (within the same consumer group!) it will continue reading from the last committed offset (101 in your example). `auto.offset.reset` specifies the behaviour in case that there is no information in `__consumer_offsets` (you do not have any commits yet).

Answer (score 0):

Offset is not realted to this. U should configure it to a property read from beginning . In java there is something like seektobeginning